# When using flutter survey_kit, how can i finish with 2 different CompletionSteps

Tags: flutter, dart, survey

I made a survey using survey_kit, and if the user enters that he is <18 years of age on a Question, i forward him to CompletionStep id: 11, if not he continues the questionaire normally and when he is at the second CompletionStep id:10, i want him to finish the questionaire, how can i add a Navigation step for him to skip CompletionStep id:11
Here you can see my first competion Step, which i want to jump to finish survey

```dart
CompletionStep(
          stepIdentifier: StepIdentifier(id: '10'),
          text: 'Danke für die Teilnahme an der Umfrage, und viel Spaß beim Spielen',
          title: 'Fertig!',
          buttonText: 'Umfrage beenden',
        );
```

```dart
task.addNavigationRule(
      forTriggerStepIdentifier: getStepIdentifier(task, "1"),
      navigationRule: ConditionalNavigationRule(
        resultToStepIdentifierMapper: (input) {
          int age = int.parse(input!);
          if (age < 18) {
            return getStepIdentifier(task, "11");
          } else {
            return getStepIdentifier(task, "2");
          }
        },
      ),
    );
```

I want something like this:

```dart
task.addNavigationRule(
        forTriggerStepIdentifier: getStepIdentifier(task, "10"),
        navigationRule: DirectNavigationRule("Finish Survey"));
```